# C++ first character does not print out using getline

Tags: c++, getline

After i run this code, it will prompt me to enter the first path e.g. c:/hello, and enter second path e.g. c:/world.

Output:

- First path: `c:/hello`
- Second path: `:/world`

As you can see the second path missing a c in front. But after i remove cin.get() after cout<<"Enter second path: "; it able to show the c in front. Can someone explain to me why is that so?

```
system("cls");
cout << "Enter first path: ";
cin.get();
getline(cin, firstPath);
cout << endl;
cout << "First path: " << firstPath << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Enter second path: ";
//cin.get(); // Need to be remove to shows c:/world
getline(cin, second path);
cout << endl;
cout << "Second path: " << secondPath<< endl;
cout << endl;
system("pause")
system("cls");
```

Comment: What is it you think `cin.get()` does?

Comment: Take in char? But first path have no issue.

Comment: So then shouldn't your question be why the first string *isn't* missing the first char? And the answer to that lies in parts of the code you haven't shown us. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your output is incorrect, the first path shouldn't show the first character as well because of `cin.get()`. It doesn't show the first character because `cin.get()` takes the first character away from the user input.

Comment: @RowenChumacera: Unless there's something left in the input buffer from a previous operation. And since the OP hasn't shown a full example, that is almost certainly the case, assuming the OP is correctly describing the output.

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR;** delete your `cin.get();` lines

---

Delete `cin.get();` it will read one character from `cin`, and so the next read from `cin` will read the next characters, so in the second case the "c" is being read by `cin.get()` and hence the next read, `getline(cin, second path)` will not read it (it has already been read). Why the "c" is being read after the first use of `cin.get()` is a mystery (perhaps you are typing a space before the "c"?

Only use `cin.get()` if you want to get the next character on the input stream and store it somewhere (e.g. `char c = cin.get()`, in this case `c == 'c'`).
If you want to skip the current character use `cin.ignore()` which does the same thing as `cin.get()`, except you can choose how many characters to skip, and it doesn't bother returning any read characters. Either way it would be inappropriate to use these in this situation.